# Obj-C GUI app with button to run shell script

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bash, user-interface

I am looking for a guide or something that will give me a demonstration of how to make a `GUI` so that I can put a button on there and link that to a script.

I currently know how to use `AppleScript Editor` to make basic apps that will present buttons and move from dialog to dialog, but what I want is a basic dialog box that would stay open until the user decides to quit ( <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> ).

Ideally, it would be able to created in Xcode. I got the general idea of how to make the interface, what I need to know, is how to link from the interface that I build, to a script that executes each time it pressed.

If someone has made a video explaining this, or can point me in the direction of a guide, that would be ideal. If you want to write out the explanation, that would be even better.

I have started to play with Obj-C a little, and in-time hope to be able to provide productive responses to others looking to commence Obj-C development too.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). It has a "do shell script" automation as well as basic automations for choosing files and presenting dialogs. Don't know off hand if there is an automation already to do exactly what you want but usually you can cobble something together.

If you already know Applescript, you can build a [AppleScriptObjc](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HE5jFCfkD0w) app in Xcode.